# Postgres ignoring search_path parameter

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, pgbouncer

I have a C# app connecting to a postgres database, through pg_bouncer, using Npgsql.  In my connection string, I include `SearchPath`.  Npgsql picks this up and sets the `search_path` parameter in the startup packet.

Pg_bouncer seems to not like that `search_path` parameter, which would cause the initial connection to fail (`Unsupported startup parameter: search_path`).  To get around this, we listed it in the ignore_startup_parameters list for pg_bouncer.

The connection now gets through to the database fine, but totally ignores any SearchPath declared in the connection string.  Every query now, instead of hitting the correct schema, selects out of the Public schema.

How can I get Postgres to respect the SearchPath again?

Answer (score 3):

You could set a default `search_path` (permanently) for the role(s) you are connecting with:

```
ALTER ROLE foo SET search_path=blarg,public;
```

Or for the whole DB, depending on your exact requirements. You can even just issue a plain `SET` statement at the top of your session / transaction. There are multiple ways to set the `search_path` in Postgres. Detailed instructions:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777)

Comment: Yes, your first suggestion is what I will fall back on.  Was just hoping to find a quick solution to the current issue to avoid any extra work.  Changing the default search_path for our users or issuing set statements would involve some redesign given our current system.